# Word for someone who is smart and illiterate

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anyone know if there is a word like this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. Are you asking for a word that means both 'smart' and 'illiterate' or are you asking for the definition of 'literacy'?

Comment: It is certainly possible to be smart and illiterate, or the opposite.  But I don't know of a single word to describe either.

Comment: It's a great question that is seldom asked. I know quite a few people who are poor readers and who are also exceptionally intelligent, so I think native intelligence is unrelated. Reading certainly increases knowledge, but knowledge cannot be equated with intelligence. To be blessed with native intelligence and to also be knowledgeable is to be truly fortunate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unrelated to English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try **[street-smart](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/street-smart)**

> Having practical rather than theoretical knowledge, such as what is learned on the streets **rather than in the classroom.** (Wiktionary)

(As opposed to [book-smart](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/book_smart)).

It's not ideal, perhaps, and may not denote illiteracy explicitly. But it comes pretty close to your requirement.

Comment: I knew someone could do it!